# if conditional of number and its increment by 16 in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have an integer called count , and i want it when it comes 1 or 17 or 33 to forever by the same sequence i.e count += 16
the first ball be unhidden , and the same thing when count comes to 2 or 18 or 34 to forever by the same sequence i.e count += 16 , the second ball to unhidden
at first i typed this code but it is very hard to type all numbers with their increments to the end in if condition

```
if(count == 1 || count == 17 || count == 33 || count == 49 || count == 65 || count == 81 || count == 97 || count == 113 || count == 129 || count == 145  || count == 161 || count == 177 || count == 193 || count == 209 || count == 225 || count == 241)
{
    _firstBall.hidden = NO;
}

if(count == 2 || count == 18 || count == 34 || count == 50 || count == 66 || count == 82 || count == 98 || count == 114 || count == 130 || count == 146  || count == 162 || count == 178 || count == 194 || count == 210 || count == 226 || count == 242)
{
    _secondBall.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: You just asked this question 5 or 10 minutes ago.  Bad form.  No, it's not different just because the numbers are different.  The formula is **exactly** the same.

Comment: Bad. Really bad. This was simple maths.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if( ((count-1) % 16) == 0) {
    _first.hidden = NO;
}

if( ((count-2) % 16) == 0) {
    _secondBall.hidden = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `%` operator returns the integer remainder (or modulus). Your first sequence: 1, 17, 33 is 16 * n + 1 so the remainder when divided by 16 is 1. Similarly your second second sequence is 16 * n + 2.

So you can:

```
switch (count % 16) // switch on the remainder of division by 16
{
   case 1:
      _firstBall.hidden = NO; break;
   case 2:
      _secondBall.hidden = NO; break;
   // add more cases if needed
}
```